# NSWindow windowDidResignKey not getting invoked after redisplaying window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I have a custom NSWindow subclass that the user can toggle the display of with the click of a button.  I'd also like the window to disappear when the window resigns key status (e.g. by the user clicking outside the window).

I have a delegate that implements `windowDidResignKey:` but I find that this delegate method is only invoked the first time the window resigns key.

Here's how I toggle the display of the window (via user action or windowDidResignKey):

```
- (void) toggleWindowAtPoint:(NSPoint)point
{
    // Attach/detach window.
    if (!attachedWindow) 
    {
        attachedWindow = [[CustomWindow alloc] attachedToPoint:point];
        attachedWindow.delegate = self;
        [attachedWindow setLevel:NSMainMenuWindowLevel+1];  // show window in front of all other apps on desktop
        [attachedWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    } 
    else 
    {
        attachedWindow.delegate = nil;
        [attachedWindow orderOut:self];
        [attachedWindow release];
        attachedWindow = nil;
    }    
}
```

Here's my implementation of windowDidResignKey:

```
- (void) windowDidResignKey:(NSNotification *)note
{
    [self toggleWindowAtPoint:NSMakePoint(0, 0)];
}
```

I'm finding that the first time the custom window is displayed, `windowDidResignKey:` gets called.  Every time the custom window is re-displayed after that, `windowDidResignKey:` is not getting invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that in some cases, the custom window was not actually becoming the key window after calling `[attachedWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self]`.

I fixed this by adding the following line before re-creating the window:

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

In the context of the code snippet above:

```
- (void) toggleWindowAtPoint:(NSPoint)point
{
   // Attach/detach window.
   if (!attachedWindow) 
   {
      [[NSApplication sharedApplication] activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
      attachedWindow = [[CustomWindow alloc] attachedToPoint:point];
      ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling [attachedWindow makeFirstResponder:attachedWindow] in your toggle method?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to activate a window without using `activateIgnoringOtherApps:` you should use a NSPanel with a NSNonactivatingPanelMask:

```
[[CustomPanel alloc] 
        initWithContentRect: NSZeroRect 
                  styleMask: NSNonactivatingPanelMask 
                    backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered 
                      defer: NO];
```